# Change the way folders are displayed in terminal

Tags: terminal, ls, colors

I moved over from Xubuntu to Fedora.

In a colored Xubuntu terminal the folders appear in bold blue wheras in Fedora they appear as normal blue.

I'm familiar with ANSI codes for colors and style but I don't know which file to edit.

**How can I make folders appear as bold blue when I type ie: `ls` in my terminal?**

Answer (score 2):

If you're refering to the output of `ls`, its manpage sent me to the `LS_COLORS` environment variable and the [`dircolors` helper program](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dircolors-invocation.html#dircolors-invocation) that can turn a list of specifications (extensions and the like, including special values like `LINK` and `DIR`) into the `LS_COLORS` you want.

`dircolors --print-database` will give you commented default settings.